# Cannot change UITabBar background image second time

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When I try to change the background image for a second time for a tab view, nothing happens.

I'm using:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:newBarImageBackGround];
```

Comment: Are you sure `newBarImageBackGround` is different the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to use something like the following for changing the tab bar's background. Unfortunately, this doesn't fly with `appearance`.

```
[[self.tabController tabBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:newBarImageBackGround]];
```

Your code should work for the first time though. Reference: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354504/setbackgroundimage-on-tabbar-does-not-work-when-tapping-items-solved)

Note: `[self.tabController tabBar]` should be replaced with whatever reference to a tab bar you're using.

**EDIT**

You could also try this, but I haven't tested it so I don't know if it'll work.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:newBarImageBackGround]];
```

Comment: supper! It works when I past it in active TabView. But how to change globally?

Comment: UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [[mainWindow.rootViewController.tabBarController tabBar] setBackgroundImage:blablabla]; - does not work

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't look like it works globally (unfortunately). The person in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354504/setbackgroundimage-on-tabbar-does-not-work-when-tapping-items-solved) had the same issue. Which means it'll have to be in each view controller.

Comment: Thnx. And why does not work [[[self navigationController] toolbar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:newBG] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];?

Comment: Only Apple knows. It *should* work, but for some reason, it doesn't. You can try my edit to the question (maybe that'll work). Please accept my answer if it helped.